# DIV in <td> float right

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I got a table with a couple `<td>`:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>First</td>
  <td>Second</td>
  <td style="padding:20px;">
      <div>
        Third
      </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to place the "Third" `<td>` (with the div) to the right side of the table and the "First" and "Second" `<td>` should stay left.

Style with `float:right;` didn't work for me...

Comment: Can't you just use `div`s with some CSS? Using tables for layout purposes is a bad idea..

Comment: What do you mean by "to the right side of the table"? Do you mean right justified within the cell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to make your table's width 100%, then control the widths of your first 2 columns, and finally right-align your third column.

http://jsfiddle.net/25Mqa/1/

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="first">First</td>
  <td class="second">Second</td>
  <td class="third">Third</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { width:100%; }
.first, .second { width:50px; }
.third { text-align:right; }
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the width of a `<table>` is determined by its content, by default. If you want the `<table>` to span 100% width (of its containing block) like block-level elements do, you can either add `table-layout: fixed;` and then specify your width - or just give it a width, depending on what you're after, e.g.

```
table {
   width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QEaAd/2/

Answer (score 1):

try add `style="text-align:right;"`

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>First</td>
  <td>Second</td>
  <td style="padding:20px; text-align:right;">
      <div>
        Third
      </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Only if you have 2 divs one near other:

```
<div id="fr">div1</div>
<div id="fr">div2</div>
```

you can float them right:

```
<style>
#fr{float:right;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
 <tr>
  <td>First</td>
  <td>Second</td>
  <td style="padding:20px; display: block; float: right;">
      <div>
        Third
      </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbesD/

I believe this does what you want, however from what I understand, floating table elements will cause problems in versions of Internet Explorer <8

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do with tables and divs? But I normally use this for emailers.

I use the align attribute for td's. This helps a lot in making sure your layout looks the way you want. And it works in all browsers :)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SVRrm/)

HTML:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td>First</td>
  <td>Second</td>
  <td style="padding:20px;" align="right">
      <div>
        Third
      </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5.2 you can add `.text-start` and `.text-end` to your text class to align elements inside a table.