# Set button position to Horizontal

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dialog and this have their buttons in vertical but I need to show these buttons in horizontal. 
so is like it see.

http://bugtrackertesting.tecnova.cl/file_download.php?file_id=20777&type=bug

I can't change the global css style , therefore I need write css for my single view.

anyone know how to set this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Share yours code or jsfiddle please

Comment: this may be odd ,  but you can use !important to override existing styles

Comment: I cannot put my code in jsfiddle because I use thymeleaf and jsfiddle don't support this library.

Comment: its hard to help without seeing code, you can also your code part in the question, i can see into  there. but if you are using table this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955366/div-in-td-float-right

Comment: thanks a lot guys, I'm going to pass this little error.

Comment: just override the css by adding in the custom css file after the global..