# CSS Float fails for HTML5 Input Elements

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm running into an issue when using HTML5 form input types (number, date, email, etc) with the CSS float property.  I'm trying to float these to the right, but they are not honoring that setting.

Here's a snippit where I put the CSS inline during testing:

```
<div class="center" style="width: 100%">
...
<div style="width: 90%" class="textfont">
...
<table style="width:100%;">
     <thead>
         <tr class="tableHeading">
             <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center;">
                 Unit Types
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                  Number of Units
              </td>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td style="border-right: 1px;">
                   Single&#45;Family Detached
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="number" name="txtDetached" style="width:25%; float:right" />
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 32px">
                    Townhouse, Row, or Cluster
                 </td>
                 <td style="height: 32px">
                     <input type="number" name="txtCuster" style="width:25%; float:right" />
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     Garden
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input type="number" name="txtGarden" style="width:25%; float:right" />
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="height: 43px">
                      Mid&#45;rise (3&#45;5)
                 </td>
                 <td style="height: 43px">
                      <input type="number" name="txtMidrise" style="width:25%; float:right" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        High&#45;rise (6&#43;)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="txtHighRide" style="width:25%; float: right" />
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Other
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtOther" style="width: 80%; float: right;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
   ...
   </div>
  ...
</div>
```

*Yes, I know tables are frowned upon...*

Here's the overall CSS:

```
    .Header
    {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Cambria;
        color: White;
        background: #254117;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .subHeading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .container
    {
        display: table;
        width: 90%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .heading
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        display: table-row;
        background-color: #C91622;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 25px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: georgia;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .table-row
    {
        display: table-row;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }

    .tableHeading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        background: #99C68E;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .textfont
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial;
        text-align: left;
    }

    input[type=text]
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 22px;
    }

    textarea
    {
        width: 98%;
    }
    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 10px;
    }
    tr
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    td, th
    {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .center
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Here's what this displays:

[image: Failing Float]

As you can see the input element with `type="text"` works without an issue, however when `type="number"` it remains at the default, left justified.

This behavior exists in IE 10, FireFox, and Chrome.

I discovered the workaround is to wrap the HTML5 input types in a div and then set the CSS to float the div right, and then this works without issue.  I had issues finding information for this on the net, but is this a known issue?  Is the workaround actually the proper way of handling this?

EDIT:  Added full CSS (minus stuff I moved inline for testing).  Added entire table and the div's they are wrapped in.  If I copy all of this to jsFiddle it works properly, so I'm obviously doing something wrong here...

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Please post all your CSS relevant to the table and its cells—an isolated case that shows your problem.

Comment: yup it is working fine as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/98h5jrbw/

Comment: [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/x02zxknv/) in chrome, ff and ie11, if you are having trouble.  Instead of floating the input right, why not just use text-align right on the td

Comment: Hmm...I must have some other CSS somewhere that's throwing me off.  Let me do some digging and I'll post an update with some more code.

Comment: @JNYRanger are you sure there are always 2 td in each tr inside the table?

Comment: @sdcr Yeah.  I'm going to post the rest of the table & CSS in a minute.  In jsFiddle I copied everything over and it works properly so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Added Additional HTML/CSS

Comment: @JNYRanger all looks fine here too. What worth trying is: get rid of all the float: right on the input, but add style="text-align: right;" on the td. see if that helps.

Comment: with your updated code, still works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/98h5jrbw/1/

Comment: @dippas Yea, I know that's what baffling me.  See my edit note.

Comment: @sdcr Thanks, I'll try that and see if that makes a difference *fingers crossed*

Comment: @sdcr That did the trick, not sure why that only affects HTML5 input type elements, but as long as it works I know how to handle this in the future.  If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem related to floating elements inside `<td>`, use `text-align` can fix it.

```
<td style="text-align:right;">
  ...
</td>
```

More can be read here [DIV in <td> float right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955366/div-in-td-float-right)